# Deny Permissions programmatically - Android

Tags: android, permissions

How can I deny granted permission programmatically in Android.
I can Add the run time permission,
Is there any way to deny the permissions on button click.

Comment: prompt for permission, using requestPermissions then tap deny ?

Comment: @nishon.tan: I need to deny the permission (Which is already granted) on a button click

Comment: you can still ask prompt request permission dialog, even if your app already has been granted the permission.

Answer (score 2):

You can't either grant or deny a permission programmatically in this way (pseudo code):

```
if(buttonpressed){
    getPermission(PERMISSiON.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).deny();
}
```

And similarly, you cannot allow a permission like this. You can, however direct the user to the permission screen and before doing that prompt the user to enable/disable the permission:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Please note that this only works if you target API 23+, and only works with **dangerous permissions**. You cannot disable the normal permissions (like INTERNET)